# How to make user sign up and login on my decentralized application?(on production it should work without metamask)

Tags: ethereumjs, ethereumj, user-safety

Assuming that user who is going to signup is not having any ethereum account so how can I generate a public, private key and address for ethereum and make use of it to make further transactions.
Users of my portal are not expected to have one ethereum account.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet to create locally in JavaScript an Ethereum wallet. You can store this wallet to a encrypted file. Your user logs in into the application by locally uploading this file and providing the password for the encryption of the keystore.

See "[How should I secure a private key in my dapp?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42028/how-should-i-secure-a-private-key-in-my-dapp/42078)" for more examples how you can implement the login to your DAPP.